# ActiveMQ Message Groups - ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

I'm using AMQ message groups with AMQ 5.6 with Kahadb persistent messaging and periodically see this WARN in the logs.  I don't see any specific errors that result from this, but am wondering what the side effects of this are, etc.

My consumer is a Camel (2.9.2) route with maxConcurrentConsumers=5 (using AMQ connection pool, etc).  I'll try to boil this down to a unit test at some point...for now, here is the stack trace

```
Async error occurred: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.doMessageSend(Queue.java:785)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.send(Queue.java:707)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion.send(AbstractRegion.java:407)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.send(RegionBroker.java:503)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedRegionBroker.send(ManagedRegionBroker.java:305)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.send(BrokerFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.CompositeDestinationBroker.send(CompositeDestinationBroker.java:96)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransactionBroker.send(TransactionBroker.java:306)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.send(MutableBrokerFilter.java:135)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processMessage(TransportConnection.java:453)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage.visit(ActiveMQMessage.java:681)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:292)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:150)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onCommand(ResponseCorrelator.java:116)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.iterate(VMTransport.java:231)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:122)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:793)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:828)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.MarshallingSupport.marshalPrimitiveMap(MarshallingSupport.java:64)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.Message.beforeMarshall(Message.java:210)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.beforeMarshall(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:199)
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v6.MessageMarshaller.looseMarshal(MessageMarshaller.java:277)
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v6.ActiveMQMessageMarshaller.looseMarshal(ActiveMQMessageMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v6.ActiveMQObjectMessageMarshaller.looseMarshal(ActiveMQObjectMessageMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.marshal(OpenWireFormat.java:168)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore.addMessage(KahaDBStore.java:429)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$StoreQueueTask.run(KahaDBStore.java:1177)
```

Comment: First recommendation is to always try the latest release due to fixes that have occurred since then.

Comment: thanks Tim, the plan is to upgrade to 5.6, but am trying to add some features prior to this.  figured I'd check to see if anything was specifically fixed in this area...didn't see any AMQ JIRAs that matched my issue, etc...

Comment: There's so many resolved issues since 5.5.0 so its hard to say for sure.  Creating a unit test that can reproduce it would make for easy validation of a newer broker release and give you something to submit in a Jira if the problem still exists.

Comment: Tim, fair enough...I'll give it a go in 5.6 as well...thx

Comment: unfortunately, I get the same issue in 5.6...

Comment: Unit test and Jira time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logged a JIRA for this ([AMQ-4092](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4092)), it sounds like an issue with a combination of KahaDB and message groups.  setting concurrentStoreAndDispatchQueues=false solves the issue (thanks to Gary Tully for the suggestion)